# Updating existing data using PATCH API call

Tags: python, api

I am trying to update some existing data using an API call as shown below:

```
import requests

url = "https://apisandbox.paylocity.com/api/v2/companies/ABC/employees/123/?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=WebLinkAPI&client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret"


payload = {'firstName' : 'Kevin'}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ACCESS TOKEN'}

response = requests.request("PATCH", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

This returns back the below message.

```
{"message":"The request entity's media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is not supported for this resource."}
```

What do I need to change to ensure I am able to update the existing data

Comment: My guess is that you should use `json=payload` instead of `data=payload`

Comment: @TheZadok42 thanks for responding. I did try using `json=payload` but it is still throwing me the same message..

Comment: Maybe you need to add the Accept header